# Aggregate data from a nested model in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables with the associations as follows.

```
STUDENTS.hasMany(REPORTS);

REPORTS.belongsTo(STUDENTS);
REPORTS.hasMany(TASKS);


TASKS.belongsTo(REPORTS);
```

**Tasks Table**

```
| id | name   | report_id   |
|----|--------|-------------|
| 01 | taskA  |         01  |
| 02 | taskB  |         02  |
| 03 | taskC  |         03  |
```

**Reports Table**

```
| id | student_id |
|----|------------|
| 01 |        01  |
| 02 |        02  |
| 03 |        01  |
```

**Students Table**

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 01 | tom  |
| 02 | jim  |
```

I am trying to create a output which looks like the following. Here i have the name of the students along with the number of tasks they have done (Linked through the reports table).

```
| student| no_of_tasks |
|--------|-------------|
|   tom  |         01  |
|  jim   |         02  |
```

The following is the query i tried using sequelize but it doesn't seem to work.

```
STUDENTS.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: REPORTS,
      attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('tasks.id')), 'no_of_tasks'],
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: TASKS,
          attributes: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  raw: true,
  nest: true,
});
```

> I am aware that this solution can be obtained using raw sql queries
>   but I am hoping to find an answer using the Sequelize js ORM.

Comment: not sure if that solves your problem but i think you're supposed to pass `nested: true` instead of `nest: true`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is intended by `nested: true`... but for this query, you are missing a group-by.  On the same level as `raw: true,` add

```
group: ['name'],
```

For this type of problem, you can debug by copying the SQL generated by sequelize and pasting into MySqlWorkbench or something similar, to see what's wrong.